# SqlError.Number descriptions

Tags: c#, .net, sql, t-sql

Where i can get all the descriptions of the SqlError.Number collection? 
This are throwed by SqlException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Description FROM master..sysmessages
```

Comment: A bit late for the party but maybe someone finds it out useful https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 10):

From `sys.messages` in your database. Since you can add your own errors in SQL Server (via `sp_addmessage`), there is no definitive list. Also, the pre-defined list (below 50000) can differ (grow) per database version.

(or do you just mean `.Message` on each `SqlError` instance?)