# How do I get the error description from an error code in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, error-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SqlError.Number descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059499/sqlerror-number-descriptions)

@@ERROR

This is an integer. How do I get the actual description of the error in the example below?

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0
INSERT INTO Table (ID, ErrorDescription)
VALUES (@ID, ????)
```

Comment: please check this SO question     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059499/sqlerror-number-descriptions.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179495%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? ERROR_MESSAGE() will work in a CATCH block. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the reference in my comment, you could something like the following:

```
SELECT @ErrorVariable AS ErrorID,
    text
FROM sys.messages
WHERE message_id = @ErrorVariable;
```

[Using @@Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: can't i just use ERROR_MESSAGE() as the variable?